# Reconcile java versions between maven and java

Tags: java, macos, maven, version, homebrew

When I'm calling `mvn --version` I get the following :

```
Apache Maven 3.8.2 (ea98e05a04480131370aa0c110b8c54cf726c06f)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.2/libexec
Java version: 16.0.2, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: US-ASCII
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

So I take the version 16 is used

But when I'm calling `java -version` :

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```

Here I have java11.

I found out that the `mvn` command (found using `which mvn`) is actually a bash script in which the JAVA_HOME variable is defined, so I do get how I'm landing into `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home` when running maven.

But what is extremely confusing is the behaviour of `java -version`. `java` refers to an executable `/usr/bin/java` that is just lying there. And if I set the JAVA_HOME :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then `java -version` returns :

```
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 16.0.2+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 16.0.2+0, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So it looks like the `/usr/bin/java` executable reads this variable and calls the corresponding "real" java exec...

But then, my paramount question is : when the JAVA_HOME variable isn't defined, how the heck is this `/usr/bin/java` executable figuring where is the openjdk in version 11 ?

Comment: /usr/bin/java is a symlink, right? See where it points. In my experience it will point to...another symlink. But keep following and you might find something useful.

Comment: Nope, it is a binary... of course, a symlink would have made sense...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is on macos `/usr/bin/java` is the same executable as `/usr/libexec/java_home`.  See the manual page for java_home(1) which references a "default order."

Comment: Mmmhhh interesting this java_home thing. Is that something that is MacOSx specific ?
It points onto a java11 version that happens to be at ``~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adopt-openjdk-11.0.11/Contents/Home/`` 

But still, I'm confused. Calling java_home returns... the path to the java install, whereas calling /usr/bin/java calls the JVM. 

Should I conclude that /usr/bin/java is forwarding the call to the java executable that is located at the java_home location ?

And btw, where is this java_jome stored ?

Comment: Yes, it is macos-specific.  As far as conclusions, I used `cmp` to verify the two executables were the same.  See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69235564/using-multiple-versions-of-java-on-my-mac/69236967#69236967) for setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable with `/usr/libexec/java_home`.