# Using Multiple versions of Java on my mac

Tags: java, zsh, macos-big-sur

I had installed Java 16 before and was using it. Now I have a need to use Java 8. After installing Java 8 I realized that the JAVA_HOME variable has to be set. I use macOS Big Sur version 11.5.2 and my terminal uses zsh shell. I followed a video on youtube that told me to do the following steps:

1. touch .zshrc
2. open -e .zshrc
3. inside .zshrc file write down the following commands

   ```sh
   export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home'
   export PATH = $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
   ```

   and save the file
4. source ~/.zshrc

but when I run the step 4 on my terminal I seem to get the following message:

```sh
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home not found
```

But I can guarantee that the directory structure is present.
Here is the output when I run
**ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home**
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUy9x.png)

Comment: Can you please post the result from running the following in terminal: `ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home`

Comment: sdkman helps to install multiple versions of java and choose the desired version.
 https://www.baeldung.com/java-sdkman-intro

Comment: The error you are getting should not happen when you're exporting a value. It shouldn't check if /Library/Java.. exists. You can write, export JAVA_HOME="THEMOON". Are you sure you're using the correct quote marks? Maybe use double quotes so you're not confused with a backtick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command.  On my machine I have:

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (10):
    16.0.1 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 16" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home
    16.0.1 (x86_64) "GraalVM Community" - "GraalVM CE 21.1.0" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java16-21.1.0/Contents/Home
    15.0.2 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 15" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home
    14.0.2 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 14" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
    13.0.2 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 13" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home
    12.0.2 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 12" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.12 (x86_64) "GraalVM Community" - "GraalVM CE 21.2.0" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-21.2.0/Contents/Home
    11.0.11 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_282+07 (x86_64) "GraalVM Community" - "GraalVM CE 21.0.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java8-21.0.0.2/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Use the following to get Java 1.8 home:

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If all the above works for your set-up, add the following to your
`~/.zshrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

Comment: Using your example above, you have 2 '16.0.1' versions. How to select between the GraalVM and OpenJDK versions? All identifiers '16', '16.0.1' etc. are the same!

Comment: I have not found a good solution for this problem.  I have been playing with something like `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 21 -X` which gives the filtered list in XML (plist). but yet haven't gone further in determinng how to query the results.

Comment: I ended up with a kludge. I edited the `Info.plist` file and updated the `JVMVersion` node with a code I can select on. Corretto v 21.0.1 and GraalVM 21.0.1 became '21.0.1_amzn' and `'21.0.1_graal' respectively, so I can use `java_home -v 21` to just picj 21, or `java_home -v 21.0.1_amzn` to select corretto, etc. Obviously, this is not a _real_ solution, I need to re-edit the plist each time I get that clash, OR make sure I keep one of them at least a minor version apart.